# subrings with identity

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there an example of a non-zero ring $R$ such that its proper subrings have identity but $R$ has no identity ?  or even is it possible that proper non-zero subrings of $R$ have the same identity but $R$ has no identity element ??

Comment: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask and then revise this question. At present, it looks like homework. If it is homework, please read http://mathoverflow.net/faq and look over other sites where your question is more appropriate.

Comment: I am new in this site. I have revised the question. 

Comment: Depending on your definition of "non-zero ring", there is a suitable object with 2 or 4 elements.

Comment: In representation theory of $p$-adic groups, one of the fundamental constructions there is of the Hecke algebra, which is the space of locally constant functions (on the group) with compact support. If you put a Haar measure on the group then this space becomes a ring, typically with no identity. However the Hecke algebra is a union of sub-algebras consisting of functions which are bi-invariant under some fixed open compact $K$, and these bi-invariant functions form a subring with identity (the identity being the characteristic function of $K$ multiplied by a suitable constant). 